# Lots of White Space Below Image

Tags: html, css

I've got a LOT of white space below my image (picture below).  And I've got no clue why it's like it.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<img src="images/testserver2.png" class="centerimage" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  height: 100%;" />

<div class="internet">
  <h3>INTERNET</h3>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.centerimage {
  display: block
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got a style attribute on your img element as well as having the CSS for the `.centerimage` class. In the style attribute there is a `height: 100%` set. 

Best practice would be to just control the CSS for your image in the CSS file like it appears you're doing in the `.centerimage` class CSS.

Comment: @dave Thanks, I just changed it, but still same issue.

Comment: can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/xtdmqaxe/

Comment: Is it possible there is a lot of whitespace on the bottom of your png file?

Comment: @dave ... I'm an idiot.  I picked the wrong picture.  :/

Please answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your image to make sure there's no whitespace embedded in the png itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implement this would be to use either the inline style attribute in your img tag or reference the CSS class.